# How to store data in sqlite database using jQuery-mobile dreamviewer cc with phonegap in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, jquery-mobile, dreamweaver

Am new in developing android app in Dreamweaver CC with Phone-gap. I designed simple form in that having 4 fields I need to store this fields in sqlite database? In eclipse import sqlite database and open database connection and then create table and store data. This is working fine, I need to do same here in Dreamweaver CC?

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
SQLiteDatabase db;
db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("QAOD", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO TableName(Id) VALUES(18)");
```

This format code is working fine in eclipse android but I need use this code and store data in sqlite in Dreamweaver CC with Phone-gap. Help me or suggest me to store data.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned you are using `Phonegap`. These are the steps to create and add records to `sqlite database` in Android

**First: Add Plugin**

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin
```

**Second: Open Database**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});
}
```

**Third: Use it (Create, Update or Delete)**

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer primary key, data text, data_num integer)');

    // demonstrate PRAGMA:
    db.executeSql("pragma table_info (test_table);", [], function(res) {
      console.log("PRAGMA res: " + JSON.stringify(res));
    });
```

You can read more [here...](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)