# What is the best way to put data in a Cordova mobile app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova

I want to put a few records for example 100. I used to put them into a .js file like this:

```
var groups = [
    {
        id: 1,
        parent_id: 0,
        name: "Group 1"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        parent_id: 0,
        name: "Group 2"
    }
];
```

but this is very hard to manage hundreds of records in a file like this.
I can't IndexedDB because I want to push data from my PC into the app. I can't use FireBase base because I want my data offline.
What should I do? Should I use SQLite?
I I should use SQLite, Is it possible to fill a db file on mt PC and put it in my Cordova app?

Comment: I think sqlite is better check this https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Comment: All things being equal, SqLite might be an *ideal* solution.  Q: What are your reservations/concerns about using SqLIte?

Comment: @FoggyDay I don;t know how to fill SQLite db on my PC and put it in my Cordova app. would you please tell me how?

Comment: @ehsanshirzadi follow my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28186434/1061944